# git --format, e.g. for `log` and `tag -l`: Are the format specifiers the same and where are they described?

Tags: git

The header is a little too general.
I wanted to list the tag annotations with some additional information
to work as change log.

Basically

```
git --no-pager tag -l --format='%(refname)   %(taggerdate)'
```

but instead of `refname` only the `tag` name, then the date, then the tag annotations.

I grepped the pages for `tag` and `log` without detailed reading.

This example is for `log`

```
git --no-pager log --no-merges --format="### %s%d%n>%aD%n%n>Author: %aN (%aE)%n%n>Commiter: %cN (%cE)%n%n%b%n%N%n"
```

The [log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) page didn't grep an identifier for the `message`.
With the links in the comments I found `contents`.

```
git --no-pager tag -l --format='## [%(refname:short)]  %(taggerdate) %(contents)'
```

is almost the solution, just a `newline` before `contents` and a date format `YYY-mm-dd`` would be better.

The `%n` for newline in `log` `--format` does not seem to work for `tag -l` `--format`.

Comment: Checked [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) already? The `format:<string>` part is just after the fixed formats description.

Comment: I did. True, they explain some of the formats in the examples. I didn't find `%(refname)` there. So the question is more "are formats reusable for `tag` and `log`? Of course `taggerdate` would be only `tag` related.

Comment: The part for tags and branches is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names). *Hey, people, stop downvoting the question, this point is arguably unclear to find in the doc* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The help page for each individual command describes what is expected, and references the other page to inspect if necessary :

```
git help tag 

   ...
--format=<format>
A string that interpolates %(fieldname) from a tag ref being shown and the object it points at.
The format is the same as that of git-for-each-ref[1]. When unspecified, defaults to
%(refname:strip=2).

# indicates to look at "git help for-each-ref"



git help log

    **Commit Formatting**
--pretty[=<format>]
--format=<format>
Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format, where <format> can
be one of oneline, short, medium, full, [...]

See the "PRETTY FORMATS" section for some additional details for each format. When = 
<format> part is omitted, it defaults to medium.

# indicates to look the the "PRETTY FORMATS" section further down the help page
```

Comment: Which basically means the formatting is not uniform across commands, e.g. `%n` does not work as newline for `tag -l --format`.

Comment: @RolandPuntaier: yes, very much so. There is a method to the madness in Git, but also a madness to the method.

Answer (score 0):

This produces a [change log](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) from the tag annotations:

```
  git --no-pager tag -l "v[[:digit:]]*" --format='## [%(refname:short)] - %(taggerdate:short) | %(contents)' | sed  "s/|/\n/g"
```

Link: https://github.com/MartinSeeler/auto-changelog-hook

I had used `sed` because I couldn't find a `newline` format from `git` doc. `%0a` is newline (comment by @lar3ry):

```
git --no-pager tag -l "v[[:digit:]]*" --format='## [%(refname:short)] - %(taggerdate:short) %0a %(contents)'
```

Comment: %0a in your --format string will give you a newline.